# UIWebView not constraining website

Tags: ios, uiwebview, storyboard

My `UIWebView` constrains and scales everything perfectly, **except for one specific case**.

When I get an infographic like this link from this specific website:

... its all **stretched out like this**...

... **instead of this** (if just opened in Safari)...

*All other links from that website work just fine, its just those infographic links/jpgs.*

I can't figure out if it has to do with it being a `jpg` or what, can you help?  Thanks!

*Here is my Storyboard and constraints:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out I needed to check the "Scales Page to Fit" box